# How to scale an object in opengl not dependent on parent's size

Tags: opengl, matrix-multiplication, glm-math

I have the following model matrix that i am using on planets and moons:

```
model =
        parentLoc
        * glm::translate(glm::mat4 (1.0), glm::vec3(distance_from_parent * cos(orbit_angle), 0.0, distance_from_parent * sin(orbit_angle))) 
        * glm::rotate(glm::mat4 (1.0), ( axis ), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
        * glm::rotate(glm::mat4 (1.0), ( rotation_angle ), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0))
        * glm::scale(glm::mat4 (1.0), glm::vec3(radius, radius, radius));
```

Note I use this for both planets and moons. My issue is the scaling.  With the function set up as it is,  I cannot use a set radius.  It has to be a ratio of its parents radius. So I'd there a way i can redo this to make it so i can set the radius variable to 6378km instead of using 0.0091677447 (which is the earth to sun ratio)?

Comment: Transform only the position relative to the parent. Rotation and size of a celestial body are independent from properties of its parent.

Comment: So should i be puking the last column from the mat4 for that?

Comment: @kingcobra1986: no, planets simply should not be parents of their moons. What if you eject a moon out if it's planet orbit? Or if you have a bi-planetary system?

Comment: @ybungalobill I'm just doing a mock up of our solar system as it is now, as a project to help me understand opengl better.

Comment: So let it be your lesson for today: if your objects are transformed independently then you should not tie their transformations to the child-parent relation. There is nothing OpenGL related to it.

Comment: So is there a way to get the location of the planet, so if I make it so the planet so if I make the planet stop the moon still rotates around that origin?

Comment: Of course there is. You already have the calculation for the planet (though you didn't show it here), so reuse those values when you calculate the moon transform.